# Visual C++ project property @ $ % macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2012 C++ project property Page, macro dialog

We can find different macro expanding syntax,

```
$(TargetPath)
%(OutputFile)
@(_TargetFramework20DirectoryItem)
```

What's the different?

---

BTW, Can we define our own new macro easily in Visual Studio 2012? Beside create a new project property sheet.

I just want to a simple new macro, if so, all my depends can be calculated base on this macro.

For example:

```
$(DependsBaseDir) = $(ProjectDir)..\..\..\
$(IncludePath) = $(DependsBaseDir)include;$(DependsBaseDir)abc\inc;$(DependsBaseDir)xyz\pub_inc
$(LibraryPath) = $(DependsBaseDir)lib
```

Using project property, I cannot archive my purpose. Since `$(DependsBaseDir)` depends on `$(ProjectDir)`. **I have to use environment variable, which is a VERY VERY BAD decision and it is hard to move project among machines.** Or I have to repeat `$(DependsBaseDir)` value everywhere. If `$(DependsBaseDir)` changed, it do change, fix depends is a disaster. I have to calculate right dots, then replace it everywhere...This simple example is hard enough. Do not say `$(SolutionDir)`, project shared in different solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ expands a property, % expands an item definition. Look at text of a vcxproj and you can see the difference.

You can define your own properties in the project file, and the suggested place is under "UserMacros". Yuo can define your thing like

$(ProjectDir)......\
there, and use it with $(DependsBaseDir) later on. AAMOF you can even use expressions applicable to C# string.

If you don't want to edit the project itself, you can put that in a separate .props file and import that manually or using the property manager.

Comment: That's it. I compared vs2010 and vs2012. The "User Macros" is new feature in vs2012. Will try it.

Comment: There is no "User Macros" in project setting in vs2012. It's still in .props file.